# Detergency and dispersancy

Tags: fluid-mechanics, measurements, engines, marine-engineering, quality-engineering

Abstract:The detergency property in oil comes from a chemical additive called detergent which has a property of preventing the deposition of carbon deposits and wash it away.
There is also this property of lube oil being Dispersant where an additive is added to divide the larger size deposits into tiny particles to be carried in a colloidal suspension evenly throughout the bulk of oil, which can be removed while filtration of the oil.

Question:Can this property of detergency and dispersancy measured so as to ascertain how much or how easily it can react and dislodge unwanted particles in an engine?

Comment: Yes it can and is - oils for diesel engines had a higher detergency performance and if put in a petrol engine in error would cause issues as some carbon build-up was acceptable as the engine aged : removing it affected the engine.